# Maximum value in a FAST Refinement

Tags: 2010, search, fast-search

I have an application that us using FAST as the back bone for a very customized search. One of the requirement that I have is to determine the highest and lowest value of a managed property. I would like this value to be pulled back from FAST in the refiners.

I have used the discretize=manual and set thresholds, I was going to use this to find the largest range that a value lies in (these values reflect a set of drop down lists of integer values that are used to show a price range) however this is limited to a maximum of 10 values and my list has 14!

So my question is how do I configure Fast to pull the maximum and minimum values in a managed property?

Adam Clifford

Comment: How do I get all possible values?
The refiner that I am sending to FAST is this currently <Refiner>propertylistingprice(discretize=manual/50/75/100/150/200/250/300/350/400/500/600/700)</Refiner> How would i set it to return indavidual values? Adam Clifford

Answer (score 1):

You can use the refiners as you suggest. But instead of putting them in buckets get all possible values and pick the max and min.